# Meteor: "cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined" & replace string with variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to use a variable instead of the string "score20130901" but If I replace the string with the following code, I get sometimes (very often) this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentflag' of undefined"

I’m using this method in other templates in the same JavaScript file and it works. But not in this template. I guess, that the page is loading too slowly or the collection is not fully loaded.

**New JavaScript (here I want to replace score20130901 with test)**

```
Template.voting.books = function () {
    var flag = Flags.findOne({_id: "bookflag"});
    test = flag && flag.currentflag;
    //alert(test);

    var books = Books.find({flag: "score20130901"}).fetch();
    return _.sortBy(books, function (book) {
        return _.reduceRight(book.score20130901, function (memo, num) {
            return memo + num;
        });
    }).reverse();
};
```

**Database**:

```
Flags.insert({
_id: "bookflag",
currentflag: "score20130901"
});
```

.

---

.

The other problem is, I'm trying desperately to replace the same string with a variable, if the string have an array with [i] like:

**JavaScript:**

```
Template.book.totalscore = function () {
    var flag = Flags.findOne({_id: "bookflag"});
    test = flag.currentflag;

    var total = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        total += this.test[i];
    }
    return total;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Template.voting.books = function () { 
    var flag = Flags.findOne({_id: "bookflag"}); 

    if (typeof flag !== 'undefined') { 
        var books = Books.find({flag: flag.currentflag}).fetch(); 
        return _.sortBy(books, function (book) { 
            return _.reduce(book[flag.currentflag], function (memo, num) { 
                return memo + num; 
            }); 
        }).reverse(); 
    }
    else return []; 
};
```

And for the second part, this:

```
Template.book.totalscore = function () {
    var flag = Flags.findOne({_id: "bookflag"});

    if (typeof flag !== 'undefined') { 
        return _.reduce(this[flag.currentflag], function (memo, num) { 
            return memo + num; 
        });
    }
    else return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be right! Your connection might not have yet fully let your database download yet. So it wont have any result for flag.

All you need to do is handle the case `flag` is `null`

```
Template.voting.books = function () {
    var flag = Flags.findOne({_id: "bookflag"});


    test = flag && flag.currentflag;
    return Books.find({flag: test}, {sort: {totalscore: -1, _id: 1}});
};
```

for your second case:

```
Template.book.totalscore = function () {
var flag = Flags.findOne({_id: "bookflag"});
test = flag && flag.currentflag;
var total = 0;

if(test) {
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        total += this.test[i];
    }
}
return total;

};
```

Comment: Problem 1: The template has been changed (see "New JavaScript in my question), but with your suggestion it doesn't work too. I get this error: TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

Comment: Problem 2: Unfortunately, that does not work. I get this error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined